# MSSQL Audits are growing out of control. 1gb every 4 minutes - any way to get size down?

Tags: sql-server, audit

I am trying to setup audits for a Veeam backup server.

I used the audit specifications from STIG - https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/ms_sql_server_2016_instance/

I haven't setup any database auditing at this point, just the server from above link.

The audit is writing 1gb every 4 minutes. Over 100gb every day!

Is there any way to get the size down? Maybe removing Select statements from audits? If so, how can I do that. Please point to a tutorial or something - I've searched for days ...

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditing should be enabled based on requirement from Compliance/IT security or Audit department of your organization. If you enable auditing as mentioned in this link, it would start auditing each and every thing. It will not only make audit files to grow rather, it would impact on performance of your instance badly.

Ideally if you follow C2 auditing, it captures basics of auditing and is accepted internationally.

> C2 Auditing and Common Criteria Compliance are two internationally
>   accepted auditing standards.
>
> C2 audit mode is the auditing option that can be used to facilitate
>   auditing standard. By enabling C2 auditing, it allows the
>   administrator to enable a comprehensive type of auditing, logging.
>   This is named as C2 audit mode because it is logging of the form
>   specified by the U.S. Department of Defense regulations to meet the
>   certification at the C2 level of trust. Those regulations were
>   specified in a document called the Trusted Computer System Evaluation
>   Criteria, often referred to as the “Orange Book” in the “Rainbow
>   Series.” The Orange Book is now depreciated in favor of the Common
>   Criteria. Nonetheless, C2 Auditing is still a commonly used term.
>
> C2 audit mode generally means assigning a unique generated audit ID to
>   each group of related processes, starting at login. Thereafter,
>   certain forms of system calls performed by every process are logged
>   with the audit ID.

You might read more about C2 auditing at this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/c2-auditing-sql-server-auditing-and-common-criteria-compliance-using-c2-audit-mode/).

There is another method of auditing accepted called "*Common Criteria Compliance*" and details are as below:

> C2 auditing has been deprecated by the Common Criteria specification
>   which was developed by the European Union. Common Criteria Compliance
>   is internationally recognized set of guidelines for security for
>   information technology products. This is applied to operating systems,
>   Databases, Network Devices and Smart cards etc. Common criteria
>   certified products have been rigorously evaluated by accredited third
>   party security labs.
>
> This option is available same versions as C2 Audit but Common Criteria
>   Compliance is available in Enterprise and Data Center editions of SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 and after versions. However, with respect to the SQL
>   Server, if you are complying with either C2 or common criteria, the
>   audit result is similar. In the case of Common Criteria Compliance,
>   audited data can be viewed from system views which is more secure than
>   the C2 audit mode.

if you enable one of them, your problem of file size and performance should go.

In case, you are really interested to get to the root of your culprit in your current scenario then, you should query your audit log and group them by action and disable that event, same can be done using below query:

```
SELECT action_id, count(*)
  FROM fn_get_audit_file( 'E:\Test\Audit-*.sqlaudit' , DEFAULT , DEFAULT)
group by action_id
```

Please remove SCHEMA_OBJECT_ACCESS_GROUP from auditing events and you should be fine for disabling select statement from audit. You can check more about this at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-schema-object-access-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are required to run audits by another company we work with. And not one of us have done it before.
If I'm stuck with that list, would it be possible to eliminate the select statements somehow? I saw somewhere that might help but it didn't show how to do it. And I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: Please remove SCHEMA_OBJECT_ACCESS_GROUP from auditing events and you should be fine. You can check more about this at --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-schema-object-access-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hey, just wanted to drop a note and say thanks for helping on this. And a special thanks for not going negative and saying "did you read my answer?"

I have re-read this thing four or five times now and saw that you posted the comment in your original answer. You could have gotten mad or even just ignored me.

But you didn't, you helped anyway. You are one of the good ones. 

And i sincerely appreciate your help!